# excel - compound interest with continuing contribution

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking for an excel formula that will apply compound interest and will allow me to add a continuous contribution for "x" amount of years.

i.e.  $10,000 contribution at 10% yearly interest every year.  I contribute $10,000 every year for the next 35 years.  What will the account value be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `FV()` formula would be what you're looking for.

```
=FV(10%,35,-10000)
```

Keep in mind, there are variations to this formula.

- `10%` assumes you only make one payment a year. If you pay 12 times a year, use `10%/12`.
- `35` is the total number of years. This doesn't change even if you change the above.
- `-10000` is your 10k / year payment

Here's where it can get interesting. Here are some optional arguments for you:

- Pv: Present Value. (Use if you are starting the account with > $0 in it)
- Type: If the "payment period" is up front of the period, then place a `1` here, otherwise omit it)

---

Here's an example for $10,000 a year in monthly payments (**12**/year), using `1` because the payments are at the *start* of the month(period), not the end.

```
=FV(10%/12,35,-10000,,1)
```